# directly spot what line of code is being executed in certain event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, debugging

Is there any way to directly spot what line of code is being executed (javascript) when clicking a button in a webpage or scrolling down .. etc?

***For example:*** Not `onMouseClick` function when clicking a button and doing debug via browser in the same time but some function like `$('#xx').click()` instead.

If so, How?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to understand, you are not wanting to use the debugger? Are you wanting to console.log the line number or something? On click events, if for what ever reason you do not know which event is firing, just put a different console.log in each event.

Comment: @Spangle I'm trying to get (via debug) `$('#xx').click()` when clicking the button which is responsible for that button event, but instead i get `onMouseClick`.

Comment: @msg Yes, exactly!

Comment: @idahoboii, try to be more precise with your question. Add code snippets showing te explain what you are doing and what you have tried until now. Sometimes, it is better to create a "minimal, reproducible example" that mimics your current situation, and is easier to understand. Refer to StackOverflow help centre to find more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: guzmonne explained well why I gave the downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always battled to find this feature in Chrome, I'm sure it's in there, *somewhere* but no one seems to be able to find it. In Firefox is quite easy: Inspecting an element will show if it has an event attached, and will even show the code. Clicking the arrow next to the file and line number will jump to that location inside the debugger.

[image: Firefox Inspector tools]

Comment: You can also add the `debugger` operator on the part of the code you want to check, and the browser will pause JavaScript execution whenever it reaches it, opening a debugger window. It is quite useful. Here you can find the docs about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger